# Wrong page numbers in the table of content when using \includepdf

Tags: table-of-contents, pdf, appendices, include

I have a book style document. I want to include two external PDF files in two separate appendices (`appendix a` for the first one, `appendix b` for the second one).

The problem: I get wrong page numbering in the appendices in the table of content. In this example, the first appendix starts correctly at page 7. The second on appears to start in page 9 in the table of contents, but it should starts in page 13. How

How can I generate correct page numbering in the table of contents when using external pdf files using `\includepdf` ?

Here is the main document script:

```
\documentclass[10pt] {book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages} 
\begin{document}
\title{Testing Title}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\lipsum
\appendix
\include{appendix1}
\include{appendix2}
\end{document}
```

The `appendix1.tex` and `appendix2.tex` script is:

```
\chapter{Appendix A} \label{appendix:a}
\includepdf[pages=-, pagecommand={}]{appendix1.pdf}
```

The PDF files `appendix1.pdf` and `appendix2.pdf` are generated with this script:

```
\documentclass[10pt] {article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\title{Testing Title}
\maketitle
\section{Section1 }
\lipsum
\section{Section2 }
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

EDIT:
This is the table of contents that I get. It is page 7, and 9 while it should be 7 and 13.
[image]

### I compile it twice. But when I compile, I get these warnings:

```
test.tex(1): Package pdfpages Warning: I will use a dummy \includepdf command which
test.tex(1): No \author given.
test.tex(1): Package pdfpages Warning: I cannot determine the number of pages of the
test.tex(1): Package pdfpages Warning: I cannot determine the number of pages of the
test.tex(1): Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.
```

Comment: I see the page numbers 7 and 13 respectively. Did you compile your main document at least twice?

Comment: Actually the doc is doing exactly what you are asking it to. It creates chapter entries and entries for then in the toc. But, as I assume you have figured out, those chapter pages has nothing but the chapter heading, the first page of the included pdf is on the next page and by default includepdf adds nothing to the toc. I recommend you have a look in the pdfpages manual, because includepdf **does** have features to add stuff to the toc.

Comment: @Christian Hupfer I edited the question

Comment: What exactly are you compiling this with? Will need pdflatex or similar

Comment: I am using MikTex 2.9 and WinShell as an editor. I use Windows. I do create pdf and compile my scripts normally without any problems. Winshell has a command (PDFLatex) and I use it.

Comment: @user6875880: The edit did not clarify the issue for me